# How to Replace Raster Values Less than 0 to NA in R code

Tags: r, raster, na

I am working with Landsat imagery to calculate net radiation. 
There are very low negative values (ex: -0.000003) that are in my converted reflectance raster layers. I want to make sure that my reflectances are 0 - 1 in order to reduce error in my future calculations.

How can I replace raster values less than 0 to "NA" in R. Similar to a raster calc function. I'm unsure how to provide an example, but I'm certain one of you could help me, yes?

Here is my equation for the reflectivity derived from Bastiaanssen et al. (1998)

Assuming, the pb1 indicates the reflectance for band 1 of Landsat, pi = 3.14..., lb1 = radiance for band 1, ESUN = exoatmospheric value for band 1, dr = the relative earth sun distance for the day of year.

```
#Calculate reflectivity per band. QC: Always 0 to 1
pb1 = (pi * lb1)/(ESUN1 * cos(solzen) * dr)
```

After this raster is created, all I want to do is set the pb1 values that are less than 0 to NA.

Help?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
library(raster)

values(pb1)[values(pb1) < 0] = NA
```

Or, as suggested by @jbaums:

```
pb1[pb1 < 0] <- NA
```

If you want to keep the original raster object, remember to assign the original raster to a new object name before running the code above.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. My new raster is classified as NA completely, though.

Comment: pb1c = (values(pb1)[values(pb1) < 0] = NA)
> pb1c
[1] NA

Comment: Do I not need to rename (ie: pb1c, c for "corrected")?

Comment: Or just `pb1[pb1 < 0] <- NA`. (And @MaeAntoinette, that will modify the original `pb1`. If you want to keep the original as well, then you can do, e.g., `pb1c <- pb1; pb1c[pb1c < 0] <- NA`).

Comment: Oh gosh! Thank you both so much. This worked @jbaums YAY!

Answer (score 37):

With the `raster` package, the memory-safe way to do this is to use `reclassify` or `clamp`

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
values(r) <- rnorm(100)
x <- clamp(r, useValues=FALSE)
y <- reclassify(r, cbind(-Inf, 0, NA), right=FALSE)
```

Note the `right=FALSE` to not set cells that are zero to `NA`.

These methods are memory-safe and you can also provide a filename argument so that you do not need to call `writeRaster` afterwards.

Comment: Rob, I don't get it... should `right` not be `TRUE` to have 0 as NA? r <-  raster(nrows=1, ncols=3)
r[] <- c(-1, 0, 1)
reclassify(r, cbind(-Inf, 0, NA), right=TRUE)

Comment: Yes, it is. But that is consistent with what I say. "right=FALSE to *not* set values of 0 to NA." such that we are doing `< 0`, not `<= 0`

Answer (score 8):

`raster::clamp` is an easy and flexible way to do this. One can set everything above and/or below threshold values to that threshold, or by setting `useValues=FALSE` then values above/below are set to `NA`. For example, lower values only:

```
r <- raster(ncol=3, nrow=3)
values(r) <- seq_len(9)
x <- clamp(r, lower=3, useValues=FALSE)
values(x)
# [1] NA NA  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

upper values only:

```
x <- clamp(r, upper=6, useValues=FALSE)
values(x)
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6 NA NA NA
```

and both upper and lower values:

```
x <- clamp(r, lower=3, upper=6, useValues=FALSE)
values(x)
# [1] NA NA  3  4  5  6 NA NA NA
```

Note the difference if `useValues=TRUE` (the default):

```
x <- clamp(r, lower=3, upper=6)
values(x)
# [1] 3 3 3 4 5 6 6 6 6
```

Using `raster_2.8-19` in this example.

Comment: I didn't know of this option. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 6):

With the `terra` package, the memory-safe way to do this is to use `classify` `clamp`, or `ifel`

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(ncol=10, nrow=10)
values(r) <- rnorm(100)
x <- clamp(r, 0, values=FALSE)
y <- classify(r, cbind(-Inf, 0, NA), right=FALSE)
z <- ifel(r < 0, NA, r)
```

These methods are memory-safe and you can also provide a filename argument so that you do not need to call `writeRaster` afterwards.

You can use `app` but that is a bit clumsy and much less efficient

```
a <- app(r, function(x) { x[x<0] <- NA; x })
```

Approaches like this are nice for interactive exploration with small data sets, but they should generally not be used in "production" code.

```
r[r < 0] <- NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is

`pb1 <- raster::calc(pb1, function(x){x[x<0]<-NA; return(x)})`