# Set values in raster to NA inside interval

Tags: r, r-raster

Assuming I would have a raster in R like :

```
r <- raster(ncols=10, nrows=10)
r[] <- sample(50, 100, replace=T)
```

How could I set the values between [10,30] for example to NA?

I tried `values = r[r<= c(10,30)] = NA` but this does not remove the values between 10 and 30.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Using

```
r[r <= 10:30] <- NA
```

seems dangerous, and in fact it gives a warning:

> Warning message:
>   In getValues(e1) <= e2 :
>     longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

It is also not memory-friendly for large rasters.

The proper/best way to do this is to use `raster::reclassify`:

```
r <- raster::reclassify(r, c(10, 30, NA))
```

, which is also much faster.

See also:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49159943/6871135

Answer (score 1):

You have to find the values like this:

```
r[r>10 & r<30]<-NA 
r[]
  [1] NA 38 NA  1 NA NA  3 32 40 36 NA NA 30  5  2 38 47 NA 42 42  1 NA NA 32 43 NA  7 NA  8 35 NA NA NA 48 10
 [36] 32 49 33 NA 48 NA 37  2 45  9  7 37 42  2 42 NA  3 49 48 NA NA 48  5 NA 46 43 NA NA NA 42 39 41 NA 48 NA
 [71] NA NA 30 35 32 46  4 32 NA 48 40  2 44 45 NA NA NA  9 47 NA NA 41  2  4 42 30 NA 36 48 32
```